# Is there a way to reevaluate the whole document twice in different OCGX layers, with some option slightly different?

Tags: ocg, layers, ocgx

I need different Layers on a Document, with the same content but different color schemes, I already know that OCGX can create layers, but I couldn't figure out how to reevaluate the document with different color schemes, and restart at the beginning to overlay the document with itself.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I am afraid its is impossible to typeset a whole (La)TeX document from the beginning more than once and to overlay the different versions afterwards in one `(la)tex` run.

Comment: At best, something like this can be achieved by manipulating the page shipping routine: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276599